# Time based query help

Tags: sql-server

I can't seem to get this to work the way I need it to. I have two tables `Assignment` and `Event`.

```
Assignment
StartDate     EndDate       Equipment
4/1/2016      4/23/2016     1001
4/3/2016      4/10/2016     1002
3/30/2016     4/20/2016     1003

Event
StartDate     EndDate       Equipment    Event
4/2/2016      4/3/2016      1001         maintenance
4/8/2016      4/10/2016     1001         maintenance
4/4/2016      4/5/2016      1002         maintenance
```

I need to join on the equipment and have an output that divides the Assignment using the events. For this sample data I would have an output that looks something like this:

```
StartDate     EndDate       Equipment    EventStatus
4/1/2016      4/2/2016      1001         Active
4/2/2016      4/3/2016      1001         maintenance
4/3/2016      4/8/2016      1001         Active
4/8/2016      4/10/2016     1001         maintenance
4/10/2016     4/23/2016     1001         Active
4/3/2016      4/4/2016      1002         Active
4/4/2016      4/5/2016      1002         maintenance
4/5/2016      4/10/2016     1002         Active
3/30/2016     4/20/2016     1003         Active
```

So for Equipment number 1001; it was put into an assignment then had maintenance twice. That maintenance split the assignment into 5 parts like so:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Active  |maintenance|  Active  |maintenance|       Active        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each of those parts must have its own row with the start and end date for that section. How can I write a query to make this work?

Comment: Where is the event status coming from? Posting any query you've come up with so far and DDL of the tables will go a long way towards people being able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution: (thanks John Eisbrener for the sample data)

```
DECLARE @Assignment TABLE
(
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE,
    Equipment VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @Assignment VALUES
    ('4/1/2016', '4/23/2016', '1001')
   ,('4/3/2016', '4/10/2016', '1002')
   ,('3/30/2016', '4/20/2016', '1003');


DECLARE @Event TABLE
(
    EventID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,2),
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE,
    Equipment VARCHAR(50),
    [Event] VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @Event 
    (StartDate, EndDate, Equipment, [Event])
VALUES
    ('4/2/2016', '4/3/2016', '1001', 'maintenance')
   ,('4/8/2016', '4/10/2016', '1001', 'maintenance')
-- Uncomment out prove it still works when stacking events back-to-back
-- ,('4/11/2016', '4/12/2016', '1001', 'maintenance')
   ,('4/4/2016', '4/5/2016', '1002', 'maintenance');

WITH AllEvents AS (

    -- Unpivot all the Assignments
    SELECT Equipment, V.EventDate, V.DateType, 'Active' AS EventType
    FROM @Assignment
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            (StartDate, 'start'),
            (EndDate, 'end')
    ) AS v(EventDate, DateType)

    UNION ALL 

    -- Unpivot all the Events
    SELECT Equipment, V.EventDate, V.DateType, [Event] AS EventType
    FROM @Event
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            (StartDate, 'start'),
            (EndDate, 'end')
    ) AS v(EventDate, DateType)

)
SELECT AE.Equipment,
    AE.EventDate AS StartDate,
    NextEvent.EventDate AS EndDate,
    EventStatus = 
        CASE 
            WHEN AE.DateType = 'end' 
                AND AE.EventType = 'maintenance' THEN 'Active'
            ELSE AE.EventType
        END
FROM AllEvents AE
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Next Event by date
    SELECT TOP(1) EventDate, EventType, DateType
    FROM AllEvents
    WHERE Equipment = AE.Equipment
        AND EventDate > AE.EventDate
    ORDER BY EventDate
) AS NextEvent
ORDER BY AE.Equipment, AE.EventDate
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit kludgy as I was unable to get a windowing function (i.e. [DENSE_RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx), [NTILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx), [RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx), or [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)) to work like I had hoped, so I had to "design" one via [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and some customizations within the table structure.

The basic premise here is you first need to join these tables to an intermediary table that contains a list of all days (e.g. an additional table I created, named #tmpDates).  This is the foundation for the output of the report as we will be grouping records to get the output you specified.  Then we work in the custom windowing function (using COALESCE here) so the steps between "maintenance" days and normal days are enumerated, but to make it work properly, I had to define an Identify Field in the Events table with a skipping increment value.

The code in all its horrendous glory is below.  If you have questions, let me know and I'll do my best to clarify, but this is garbage... working garbage.  I'm hoping someone can get this working with a ranking function instead of my awful hack-and-slash fest with COALESCE:

```
-- Build out Tables to Show Example
CREATE TABLE #tmpAssignment
(
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE,
    Equipment VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpAssignment VALUES
    ('4/1/2016', '4/23/2016', '1001')
   ,('4/3/2016', '4/10/2016', '1002')
   ,('3/30/2016', '4/20/2016', '1003')

-- NOTE: Make sure the identity field Skips a number to allow for windowing in the report
CREATE TABLE #tmpEvent
(
    EventID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,2),
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE,
    Equipment VARCHAR(50),
    [Event] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpEvent 
    (StartDate, EndDate, Equipment, [Event])
VALUES
    ('4/2/2016', '4/3/2016', '1001', 'maintenance')
   ,('4/8/2016', '4/10/2016', '1001', 'maintenance')
-- Uncomment out prove it still works when stacking events back-to-back
-- ,('4/11/2016', '4/12/2016', '1001', 'maintenance')
   ,('4/4/2016', '4/5/2016', '1002', 'maintenance')

-- Create a Join Table comprising of Dates
CREATE TABLE #tmpDates
(
    DateField   DATE
)

DECLARE @dField DATE
SET @dField = '3/15/2016'

SET NOCOUNT ON

WHILE @dField < '5/15/2016'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpDates VALUES (@dField)
    SET @dField = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dField)
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF


;WITH CTE_report
AS
(
    SELECT  d.DateField, a.Equipment, --e.[Event], e.EventID
        COALESCE(e.[Event], 'none') AS [Event], 
        COALESCE(
            -- Pull Event if Occurred
            e.EventID, 
            -- Window Before or In Between Events - This is horribly inefficient
            (SELECT MIN(EventID) - 1 FROM #tmpEvent te WHERE d.DateField < te.StartDate AND a.Equipment = te.Equipment), 
            -- Final Window After All Events - This is also horribly inefficient
            (SELECT MAX(EventID) + 1 FROM #tmpEvent te WHERE a.Equipment = te.Equipment), 
            -- No Events for a Given Assignment
            0) AS EventID
    FROM    #tmpDates d
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpAssignment a
                ON d.DateField >= a.StartDate
                    AND d.DateField <= a.EndDate
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpEvent e
                ON d.DateField >= e.StartDate
                    AND d.DateField <= e.EndDate
                    AND a.Equipment = e.Equipment
    WHERE   a.Equipment IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  MIN(DateField) AS StartDate, MAX(DateField) AS EndDate, Equipment, [Event]
FROM    CTE_report
GROUP BY Equipment, [Event], [EventID]
ORDER BY 3, 1


-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #tmpAssignment
DROP TABLE #tmpEvent
DROP TABLE #tmpDates
```